# SoftLayer API: Missing active preset values for package 200 hourly bare metal servers

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We noticed we got the error from SoftLayer API when trying to get categories from

product package 200 ( hourly bare metal server) preset `Id=64` starting 10/18.

The following API query

```
https://<apiuser>:<apikey>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getActivePresets.json?objectMask=mask
[id,packageId,description,name,keyName,isActive,categories.id,categories.name, categories.categoryCode]
```

now returns `presetId` as  `103, 97, 93,95,99,101,105,151,147,149, 143, 157`

It used to return the following additional active presetIds:
`64,66,68,70,74,76 , 78`  before `10/17/2016`.

I don't find these changes from SoftLayer release note 
https://softlayer.github.io/release_notes/

Why are the previous active preset Ids 64,66,68,70,74,76 , 78 no longer available? Will they be added back ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody please help looking into this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, these presets are not longer available since **10/17/2016**, because the DCs are no longer building the configurations and have moved to the **Haswell** and **Broadwell** configurations.

- **For Haswell:**

  - Presets: 93, 95, 97, 99, 101, 103, 105
- **For Broadwell:**

  - Presets: 147, 149, 151, 153, 157.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any plan of adding back the ones available before 11/17 soon ? This is just for our information.  Can SoftLayer please notify users such changes of removing/adding product presets in advance in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no any plan to adding back, but I suggest to contact Sales team, in order that they can provide more information. My apologies for no communication about this, I will let know this suggestion to the proper person.

Comment: It's fine if there's no plan to add back those discontinued presets. We only require advanced notice when removing existing product or adding new product. Thanks.

Comment: According to Sales team, this information was communicated last week

Comment: Is there a link to that communication? I'll check it frequently.   I checked the release note link https://softlayer.github.io/release_notes/.  That is not listed on the release note.

Comment: According to them, these notifications are done by mail and tickets